# Summary Row will Hide on Some Filtering - RadGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have a grid view which shows list of my customers and every customer has an ID.
I have added a Summary Row at top to count customers based on ID Column.
Every thing is good, when I filter grid view by customer's name or family the summery row will show its counter very well.
But when I filter the grid by customer's ID the summary row will hide!
for example if I filter grid to show only customer with ID = 121, the summary row will hide but it should be visible and show 1 as count.

Here is a piece of code which I used to filter the grid:

```
            this.gridCustomers.Columns["IDCol"].FilterDescriptor = new FilterDescriptor
            {
                Operator = FilterOperator.IsEqualTo,
                Value = "121"
            };
```

And I have set the summary row via design mode.

Where is the problem?

Comment: May I ask for a code sample? Anything that could help reproducing this behavior...

Comment: @PierreLebon the post updated

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. There is no reason for the `SummaryRow` Collection to be cleared on filtering. In fact it works fine in a ![sample project.](http://imgur.com/a/uB2kS)perhaps the issue is in the declaration of the `SummaryRows`.